# Why do relative and absolute paths hence different results?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, java-web-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : File.exists() inconsistencies when setting “user.dir”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275362/java-file-exists-inconsistencies-when-setting-user-dir)

Why does this:

```
void test(){
  print(new File("downloads/"));
  print(new File("downloads/").getAbsoluteFile());
  print(new File("C:\\someDir\\downloads\\"));
}

void print(File dir){
  log.info(dir.getAbsolutePath() + " exists " + dir.exists() + " contains: " + (dir.list() != null ? dir.list().length : "") + " files");
}
```

prints this:

```
C:\someDir\downloads exists true contains: 0 files
C:\someDir\downloads exists true contains: 1 files 
C:\someDir\downloads exists true contains: 1 files
```

when executed via JUnit in Maven in Jenkins as a WebStart slave?

Comment: Is it possible that you modified `user.dir` via `System.setProperty()`? If so, then that's your problem, because that's not supported!

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275362/java-file-exists-inconsistencies-when-setting-user-dir

Comment: @JoachimSauer: you are right, thanks! I gonna vote for close as duplicate.

Comment: Glad to have helped, I wouldn't have voted to close as duplicate without feedback (since it *could* have been a different problem), but if you can confirm that this is the same problem, then I'll vote to close as well.