# File not found in user.dir

Tags: java

I have a simple line of code that should print out first line of a file:

```
System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file")).readLine());
```

The class file with this line is located in `c:/users/my/project`. 
A file named "file" exists in `c:/users/my/project`. 
If I open CMD, navigate to `c:/users/my/project` and run

```
java MyClass
```

The first line is printed out and everything is fine.

But if I navigate to `C:/` in CMD, and run

```
java -Duser.dir=c:/users/my/project MyClass
```

I get a response that file "file" could not be found.

If I move "file" to c:/ and run the same command again then it is found.

As I understand it, changing the `user.dir` should be equivalent to me being in the folder that it points to but that doesent seem to be true. The class file is found in `user.dir`, but files are still found in the folder I ran the command in, not the folder that `user.dir` points to.

Why is this?

Comment: Could you try just before the System.out.println: `System.out.println("user.dir: " + System.getProperty("user.dir")); System.setProperty("user.dir", "c:/users/my/project");`

Comment: try -Duser.dir=/users/my/project

Comment: @JoopEggen Added those lines, it prints out the correct user.dir. Output: user.dir: c:/users/my/project
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: @BorisChistov tried it. Class file is found as it was previously, but i still get file not found exception: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Is there any specific reason you use the old file API instead of NIO? (`Files`, `Paths`, `Path`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to another directory and try to run your program with a different `user.dir`, you also have to set the classpath. The error you get is because it can't find the class, not because it can't find the file.

Try

```
java -Duser.dir=c:/users/my/project -classpath c:/users/my/project MyClass
```

Regarding the `user.dir` property, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for the `File` class. It states

> A pathname, whether abstract or in string form, may be either absolute or relative. An absolute pathname is complete in that no other information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes. A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property `user.dir`, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

**EDIT**

I did a test on my machine and found that file reader looks in the directory that the application was launched from (which may not coincide with the `user.dir` property). See below:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("abs path to test.txt : " + new java.io.File("test.txt").getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("user home : " + System.getProperty("user.home"));
        System.out.println("user.dir : " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.out.println("running from : " + new java.io.File(".").getAbsolutePath());

        System.out.println(new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader("test.txt")).readLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
}
```

Launching this from a directory that doesn't have the file in it I get

```
C:\Users>java -Duser.home=C:\Users\william -Duser.dir=C:\Users\william -classpath C:\Users\william\Desktop Test
abs path to test.txt : C:\Users\william\test.txt
user home : C:\Users\william
user.dir : C:\Users\william
running from : C:\Users\william\.
Not found
```

Whereas launching it from a directory that has the file I'm looking for I get

```
C:\Users\william>java -Duser.home=C:\Users\william -Duser.dir=C:\Users\william -classpath C:\Users\william\Desktop Test
abs path to test.txt : C:\Users\william\test.txt
user home : C:\Users\william
user.dir : C:\Users\william
running from : C:\Users\william\.
hello world
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I'm using the openjdk 8, so in my case the logic is as follows, from its source:

**FileReader** constructor with `String` arg

```
public FileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(new FileInputStream(fileName));
}
```

**FileInputStream** constructors

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);
}

public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String name = (file != null ? file.getPath() : null);
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkRead(name);
    }
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if (file.isInvalid()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Invalid file path");
    }
    fd = new FileDescriptor();
    fd.attach(this);
    path = name;
    open(name);
}
```

**FileInputStream** `open(String)`

```
private void open(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    open0(name);
}
```

The `open0(String)` method is a native call (see below)

```
private native void open0(String name) throws FileNotFoundException;
```

Digging deeper, into the native call in **FileInputStream.c**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_io_FileInputStream_open0(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jstring path) {
    fileOpen(env, this, path, fis_fd, O_RDONLY);
}
```

Therefore the `name` is what becomes the `path` that the native `fileOpen` method will use. This translates to `file.getPath()`, which is different from `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

> `file.getPath()` with `file` as `new File("test.txt")` returns `test.txt`, which may not be found.

That's the best I can do, I hope it helps.

See this [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4117557) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275362/java-file-exists-inconsistencies-when-setting-user-dir). In short, setting the user.dir via the command line is bad news.

Comment: I dont think you are correct. The error i got was not because of class not found, it was file not found: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file (The system cannot find the file specified). Also I added code to print out all entries of classpath to beginning of my code. When launching the class with my command: java -Duser.dir=c:/users/my/project MyClass from c:/ then only classpath entry is c:/users/my/project so it seems classpath is set to user.dir automatically.

Comment: @donaldtbd Interesting question, I did some tests and updated the answer

Comment: So it seems to a bug/feature of FileReader?

Comment: @donaldtbd I updated the answer again, it's just the expected behaviour, at least with openjdk 8

Comment: But that "expected behaviour" goes against the documentation that states: "By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked."

Comment: @donaldtbd I found some more info, updated the question again. Basically you shouldn't count on setting `user.dir` from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting FileNotFound exception because the program is not able to find the file you are trying to read (In your case fileName is also "file").

The problem is coming because you have defined only the file name not the path. You should either give absolute or relative path for it to make work from any directory. In absence of the path definition the program will try to read from a file in current directory from where your command is executing.

Let's dive into the details:
you have the text file in path : c:/users/my/project/file
You have your Java file in path : c:/users/my/project/MyClass

now when you run inside c:/users/my/project directory , you get the expected output because the text file "file" is defined in this directory only.

when you switch to c: and try to run the program, you get exception because it is trying to find "c:/file" which does not exist.

try to change the line to mention absolute path instead:

**System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/users/my/project/file")).readLine());**

Comment: Thats my point. It should not be looking for the file in c:/file because of user.dir property i defined. If you read documentation of file: "By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked" FileReader is in java.io package, and my user.dir is set to c:/users/my/project so i expect it to look for the file there, but it doesent.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java/840229#840229 it seems only changing the user.dir will not help.
you need to give the user.dir path as relative path in program too : **System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "file1"))).readLine())**